# Планировщик заданий Open Server и CakePHP 3

Tags: openserver, cakephp

Помогите запустить консоль `Cake` в планировщике заданий.
Пробовал по инструкции [с сайта](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html) и получилось что-то вроде этого:

```
%progdir%\modules\php\%phpdriver%\php-win.exe -c %progdir%\modules\php\%phpdriver%\php.ini -q -f %sitedir%\redfilm3.org\bin\cake.php myshell
```

но ничего не вышло, код не отрабатывает.
в php.ini `register_argc_argv = On`

Comment: вы в консоли то просто запустить для начала можете шелл свой?

Comment: зы: в примерах опенСервера путь к ini-файлу берется другой

Comment: и как вариант перенаправьте вывод в файл `> out.txt`, может там ошибки сыпятся какие. или логи кейка посмотрите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

чуть голову не сломал с этим openserver.

В общем,  имеем шелл (`\src\Shell\TestShell.php`):

```
<?php
namespace App\Shell;
use Cake\Console\Shell;
use Cake\Log\Log;

class TestShell extends Shell {

    public function main(){
        Log::debug('test shell output');
    }

}
```

Добавляем задачу

```
*/1 * * * * 
%COMSPEC% /c %progdir%\modules\php\%phpdriver%\php-win.exe -c %progdir%\modules\php\%phpdriver%\php.ini  -q -f %sitedir%\site.ru\app\bin\cake.php test
```

различие с вашим вроде в запуске через консоль `%COMSPEC%`, без нее не хочет.

*зы: в мануале опенсервера прописан конфиг из `temp` но явно ошибка, ибо он туда если и генерируется, то с отключенными расширеняими и cake не стартует.*

Comment: Вот спасибо мил человек! Действительно, добавил %COMSPEC% и всё заработало.