# Настроить планировщик заданий open server

Tags: openserver, планировщик-задач

Каким образом прописать команду чтобы каждую минуты выполнялся скрипт?

сделал так:

```
http://site.ru/script.php
```

Время `*/1 * * * *`

Но ничего не выполняет. В логах:

> 25 Oct 17:01:00 Start: http://site.ru/script.php
>
> 25 Oct 17:01:00 Start result: 0

Мне нужно чтобы выполнялся скрипт на сайте.

Comment: вам обязательно выполнять скрипт через вэб? нельзя его выполнить локально из консоли что ли? как то это не нормально выглядит

Comment: [Возможный дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/720322/223826)

Comment: ну или скорее [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/729747/223826)

Comment: но если вам требуется выполнять запрос к чужому сайту, то решение будет несколько другое, [например,  с использованием  скприта PowerShell](https://superuser.com/a/330754). Либо своего пхп скрипта, который обращается по указанному URL

Answer (score 2):

Для вашего вопроса есть два варианта развития событий:

1. **Вы выполняете скрипт на своем сервере**.
   В данном случае, вы имеет доступ к скриптам напрямую, и нет необходимости выполнять скрипты через `http` протокол. Вы просто запускаете его.
   Строка запуска будет иметь вид: `*/1 * * * * php "d:\path\to\script.php"`
   Немного подробнее смотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/729759/223826).
2. **скрипт необходимо выполнить на удаленном сервере**.
   То есть необходимо обратиться к удаленному ресурсу. В данном случае, вам потребуется некоторый промежуточный инструмент, который будет выполнять непосредственное обращение. Это можно сделать опять же с помощью интерпретатора php, либо, например, команды powershell. Поскольку, предположительно пхп у нас уже есть то:
   `*/1 * * * *  php "file_get_contents('http://site.ru/script.php')"`