# Запуск php файла каждую минуту через "Планировщик задач" Open Server

Tags: php, cron, openserver

Написал код на PHP, который выполняет некоторые действия, и в итоге добавляет данные в БД.

Надо, чтобы он запускался сам каждую минуту. Решил использовать `crontab`. На windows сделать это оказалось муторнее. Благо у OpenServer есть функция "Планировщик задач" в настройках. 
Запустил его с таким указанием:

```
*/1 * * * * W:\modules\php\PHP-5.6-x64\php-win.exe -c W:\userdata\config\PHP-5.6-x64_php.ini -q -f W:\domains\test.com\parser.php
```

Как видите мне надо запускать `parser.php` каждую минуту.

Но почему-то кронтаб не работает. В логах пишет:

```
08 Jan 00:21:56 Start nnCron
08 Jan 00:21:56 Load cron.tab
08 Jan 00:22:00 Start: W:\modules\php\PHP-5.6-x64\php-win.exe -c W:\userdata\config\PHP-5.6-x64_php.ini -q -f W:\domains\test.com\parser.php
08 Jan 00:22:00 Start result: 0
08 Jan 00:23:00 Start: W:\modules\php\PHP-5.6-x64\php-win.exe -c W:\userdata\config\PHP-5.6-x64_php.ini -q -f W:\domains\test.com\parser.php
08 Jan 00:23:00 Start result: 0
08 Jan 00:24:00 Start: W:\modules\php\PHP-5.6-x64\php-win.exe -c W:\userdata\config\PHP-5.6-x64_php.ini -q -f W:\domains\test.com\parser.php
08 Jan 00:24:00 Start result: 0
```

Но когда проверяю базу данных, новых данных нет. А при открытии этого же файла в браузере данные добавляются. (при каждом обновлении страницы)

Подскажите, где я оплашал?

Comment: @teran Спасибо за изменения. Я нашел ответ на свой вопрос. Стоит написать его сюда?

Comment: конечно стоит, если вопрос конечно не является дубликатом заданных здесь ранее, хотя и это не мешает опубликовать ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Неправильно задано указание "Планировщику задач". Надо изменить его на:
`W:\modules\wget\bin\wget.exe -q --no-cache http://test.com/parser.php`

Comment: если файл доступен локально нет смысл выполнять его через вэб. Ознакомьтесь с этим ответом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/735801/223826 и еще одним там по ссылке. В вашем случае проблема скорее в отсутствии кавычек.